# How to loop a JSON nested Array into table list

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, nested

Hi I am trying to read a nested JSON array data into a table and as a list not just in a line.
Look, at the way it comes out:
[image: Problem - it's just one lone line]

Link to JSON: [JSON](https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export)
L: demo
P: ocfB6XzF73
Documentation: [URL-DOC](https://developer.bilinfo.net/content/Bilinfo_XML_API.pdf)

JSON code I am trying to reach:

```
"EquipmentList": [ "ABSBrakes", "Alarm", "AlloyRims", "AntiSpin", "AutomaticGear", "RemoteCentralLocking", "PoweredWindows", "PoweredMirrorsHeated", "CruiseControl", "InfoCenter", "AutomaticClimateControl", "TripComputer", "Navigation", "GearShiftStearingWheel", "ServiceOK", "Immobilizer", "SeatHeater", "XenonLight" ]
```

My code so far i very simple as I struggle to list the data to a list i.e. LI or a TABLE :

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export';

// provide your username and password here
$auth = base64_encode("demo:ocfB6XzF73");

// create HTTP context with basic auth
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]
]);

// query for data
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
// $escaped = json_encode($data);
$escaped = json_decode($data); //, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

/*Initializing temp variable to design table dynamically*/
$temp = "<table>";

/*Defining table Column headers depending upon JSON records*/
$temp .= "<tr>";
$temp .= "<th>Bil</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Model</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Motor</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Drivmiddel</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Udstyr</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Billeder</th>";
$temp .= "</tr>";


/*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
foreach ($escaped->Vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $temp .= "<tr>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Make . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Model . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Motor . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Propellant . "</td>";


    foreach($escaped->Vehicles[0]->EquipmentList as $EquipmentItem){
        $temp .= "<td>" . $EquipmentItem . "</td>";
    }
    for ($p = 0; $p < $vehicle->PictureCount; $p++) {
        $temp .= "<td><img src='" . $vehicle->Pictures[0] . "'></td>";
    }
}
$temp .= "</tr>";
/*End tag of table*/
$temp .= "</table>";

/*Printing temp variable which holds table*/
echo $temp;

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: $temp .= "</tr>"; please paste it to foreach

Comment: It works... But it break's up the code :) I have to re-think the table then...

Comment: plz post answer so I can check it for you :)

Comment: Sorry martin, I was super busy on migration that day. I am glad that you resolved problem yourself. This is the quality of dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Anand Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7188473/anand-pandey)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export';

// provide your username and password here
$auth = base64_encode("demo:ocfB6XzF73");

// create HTTP context with basic auth
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]
]);

// query for data
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
// $escaped = json_encode($data);
$escaped = json_decode($data); //, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

/*Initializing temp variable to design table dynamically*/
$temp = "<table class='car-list'>";

/*Defining table Column headers depending upon JSON records*/
$temp .= "<tr>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Bil</th>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Model</th>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Motor</th>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Drivmiddel</th>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Udstyr</th>";
$temp .= "<th class='th-style'>Billeder</th>";
$temp .= "</tr>";


/*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
foreach ($escaped->Vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $temp .= "<tr>";
    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>" . $vehicle->Make . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>" . $vehicle->Model . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>" . $vehicle->Motor . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>" . $vehicle->Propellant . "</td>";


    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>";
    foreach ($escaped->Vehicles[0]->EquipmentList as $EquipmentItem) {
        $temp .= "<table>";
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td class='equipmentlist'>" . $EquipmentItem . "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
        $temp .= "</table>";
    }
    $temp .= "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>";
    for ($p = 0; $p < $vehicle->PictureCount; $p++) {
        $temp .= "<table>";
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>";
        $temp .= "<img class='cc-images' src='" . $vehicle->Pictures[$p] . "'>";
        $temp .= "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
        $temp .= "</table>";
    }
    $temp .= "</td>";
}
$temp .= "</tr>";
/*End tag of table*/
$temp .= "</table>";

/*Printing temp variable which holds table*/
echo $temp;

//echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).